# Redirect every request from https to http in codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

My htaccess looks like :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

if user opens url like https://example.com. it should redirect to http://example.com.

but now when i open url like https://example.com it gives **This webpage is not available**.

I tried one more code to redirect **https** to **http** in config.php:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTPS']) 
{  
        $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 
        $request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
        $good_url = "http://" . $host . $request_uri; 
        $config['base_url'] = $good_url;
        header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
        header( "Location: $good_url" ); 
        exit; 
}
```

None of them works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.htaccess` code is incorrect.

The code you used (shown below) says, "If HTTPS is on, then redirect to the HTTPS version," which is not what you want.

```bsh
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

In addition, those rule are placed at the bottom of the file, not at the top.

To fix it, use the following `.htaccess` instead:

```bsh
RewriteEngine on

# Turn off HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Send everything else to the CI front controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Be sure to remove the code you added to `config.php` - it is not necessary.

Comment: still **This webpage is not available**

Comment: That error looks like it comes from Chrome, not from your server. Please refer to the following link to try and diagnose and solve: https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1085581?hl=en

Comment: same thing happening in mozilla

Comment: Is the error exactly the same in Firefox? As in, does it say the same thing and look the same? Perhaps a screenshot will help.

Comment: That server is not responding. The `.htaccess` code is correct, and is not causing this issue. Perhaps Apache has not started?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81537/discussion-between-kiran-arya-and-mike-rockett).